# Where to find measures of a WPF TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a very special tree view, by designing the nodes as individual views implemented using HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
<!-- ... -->
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContentFrom}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}" >
          <local:IndividualTreeNodeView />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
<!-- ... -->
```

The problem now is, that I need some more information than only the size of the tree view to design the **IndividualTreeNodeView** right.
I need the distance from the first node from the border, and the "depth" of each level of the tree node.

[image]

From the screenshots I see that the first not has in insert of 22px, and each level another 19px. But I dont want to check screenshots.

Wehere are those values available to read ouf of the TreeView or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the most ellegant way to solve this but this should help:

```
            Point p0 = YourTreeView.PointToScreen(new Point());
```

returns the position of the treeview

```
            Point p1 = YourTreeViewItem.PointToScreen(new Point());
```

returns the postion of the treeViewItem
the result gives you their delta (p0.X-p1.X)  and out of this you can calculate its "depth" in the TreeView

Alternativly you can try to climb up the visual tree starting at your TreeViewItem using a loop and Control.Parent to count the TreeViewItems above to get its "depth" before you hit the treeView (code not tested im on my phone)

```
        TreeViewItem item = YourTreeViewItem;
        int depth = 0;
        while(item.Parent.GetType() != typeof(TreeView))
        {
            depth++;
            item = item.Parent as TreeViewItem;

        }
```

unfortunately there is no parameter you can excess directly to get the "depth"